# How to get last updated document in MongoDB with official C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

**Edit** ========================

Suppose you have 10 documents in your collection, and you want to reserve random document in it, so that no other request could also use it, for that purpose I'm using atomic **$set** and field "taken", after the document is set **"taken"** to **true** it is no longer participates in query, so it can't get used by any other request to database, the only problem is that after it is "taken" I don't know how to get the document that just had been updated.

**Edit** ========================

I'm having difficulty with obtaining a document that was just modified.

**Example:**

Sample documents:

{"_id":"a...", "age":23, "taken": false}

{"_id":"b...", "age":25, "taken": true},

{"_id":"c...", "age":27, "taken": false},

{"_id":"d...", "age":27, "taken": true},

{"_id":"e...", "age":29, "taken": false},

{"_id":"f...", "age":29, "taken": false}

**The code:**

```
collection.Update(Query.And(Query.GTE("age", 26), Query.EQ("taken", false)), Update.Set("taken", true));
```

I need a way to get the record that was "taken", is there a way to do that?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you clarify your question, it's not clear what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'FindAndModify' method, which updates a single document, and then returns that document.

```
var query = Query.And(Query.GTE("age", 26), Query.EQ("taken", false));
var update = Update.Set("taken", true);

var result = collection.FindAndModify(
    query, 
    update, 
    true // return new document
);

var chosenDoc = result.ModifiedDocument;
```

The C# documentation is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-FindAndModifymethod), and the general information on findAndModify is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

Answer (score 2):

C# driver has a method "FindAndModify" it can return last updated document